# In other topologies on $\Bbb R^n$, is multiplication always a continuous function?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In $\Bbb R^n$ usual topology, multiplication is a continuous function. But in other topologies on $\Bbb R^n$, is multiplication always a continuous function?

Comment: No, this is impossible:  won't continuity wildly depend on the topology?  Consider the indiscrete or included point topologies.

Comment: @Randall's comment is really good advice for a whole range of questions. You need to become familiar with, and remember, around half-a-dozen topologies, starting with "usual", discrete, indiscrete. Then when you get a question like this quickly try your checklist of topologies. That often disposes of the  question.

Comment: What is multiplication in $\mathbb R^n$? Scalar multiplication with reals?